# Center image vertically and horizontally in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I want to achieve:

Center an image horizontally and vertically in the right flexbox item as shown in this picture:

[image]

What's the best way to do it?

Here's my Codepen: https://codepen.io/AlexZeitler/pen/JayvNg

I got the image centered horizontally but not vertically using this `.grid-right` class:

```
.grid-right {
    width: 67%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the height of the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.grid-right {
  display: flex;            /* new */
  align-items: center;      /* new */
  justify-content: center;  /* new */
  width: 67%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPaqqQ)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  /* for the demo */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  /* makes the image gets centered */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* horizontal centering */
  align-items: center; /* vertical centering */
}

img {
  /* for the demo */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/1200px-Tux.svg.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following to center an image vertically and horizontally in flexbox:

```
.grid-right {
    width: 67%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;            /* new */
    align-items: center;      /* new */
    justify-content: center;  /* new */
}
```